# Couldn't download several files Programmatically through <a> tag

Tags: javascript, browser, download

My node server sends links to the client to download by creating  tag and triggering it. But that way I am able to download **only one file**.
My **handleDownload** function:

```
 //imageUrls is a array containing links
 function handleDownload(){
  for(let i=0;i<imageUrls.length;i++){
    downloadAnImage(imageUrls[i])
  }
 }
```

My **downloadAnImage** function:

```
 function downloadAnImage(imageLink){
  let link=document.createElement('a');
  link.href = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY+"/download/"+imageLink
  link.download = imageLink;
  link.click();
 }
```

By the way, **only the last link of the array gets downloaded**.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayOfLinks = ['https://link1.com', 'https://link2.com', 'https://link3.com', 'https://link4.com']

function handleDownload(array) {
  array.forEach((link) => {
    window.open(link, '_blank')
    // you can also use _parent as the second argument to the window.open 
    // function if you want to get that downloaded in the parent frame
    // Even if you use _blank it will open in a new page, and will close once the user allows it to download
  })
}

handleDownload(arrayOfLinks)
```

PS: This will work if the pop-ups are not blocked in the browser settings.

Comment: Let me know in case you need more clarity with the answer

Comment: Did modification to the function with `window.open()` but same result. Only first link get downloaded

Comment: Can you share the links, at least two. So that I can repro it locally and come up with a more concrete solution.

Comment: The easiest way you can repro is by creating an array of links, and loop through each links with `window.open()`. Sorry I couldn't give you the code link, because it's my clients property.

Comment: I tried and it's working for me, could you please try with any other browser